# Basic Geometry Problem to find area of a region on a circle

Tags: geometry, circles, area

[image]

**[Problem]** 
Let C, E, F, and D be points on a circle. Suppose G is the intersection point of CD and EF. Furthermore, $\angle DGE = \angle FGC = 120^{\circ}$, $\angle GHI= \angle GJI= 90^{\circ}$, and $\angle CAE = 60^{\circ}$. Moreover, we know that $|GH| = |GJ| = \sqrt[4]{48}$  If the area of the region CGF is the same with the area of region of EGD that is $30 \, cm^{2}$ find the total area of region of CGE and FGD!

My attempt so far in the problem is that I know $|HI| = |IJ| = \frac{\sqrt[4]{48}}{\sqrt{3}}$ and the triangle AGB is an equilateral triangle. However, I do not know how to use this information to solve the question. Anhe help is much appreciated! Thank you and I am sorry to ask such basic elementary geometry problem!

Comment: I apologise, it should be DGE… I will edit

Comment: You refer to triangle AGB, but in the sketch A and G seem to be the same point. Also, how do we know where B is? It's shown on the circle, but it isn't clear to me what its exact location is.

Comment: Could you please clarify which points are given? C, E, F, D, G are clear. But A, B, I, J, H? Moreover, A=G or A lies in CGF or in DGE. Its position in the figure is misleading.

Comment: A is the center of the circle so it is not he same with G. B is just not important. I apologize for that. H lies on EF and J lies on CD. I is a point which connect HI and IJ.

Comment: There is no way to determine the areas with the information provided. If G coincides with A, the area of CGE and FGD is 30 $cm^2$. But if G is on the circumference, the area is much larger. G can be too many places.

Comment: @SteveB I believe he is probably referring to $\triangle ACE, \triangle AFD$ when he referred to an equilateral triangle.

Comment: @John Glenn Quite likely. Sadly, the problem is unworkable in it's present form. Now if H and I were the midpoints of the segments they are sitting on, I think that would pin down G well enough to solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the comments! I appreciate all the advices here. Maybe, this problem is not workable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\angle DGE = \angle FGC = 120^{\circ}$, 
then we can easily check that $\angle CGE = \angle FGD = 60^{\circ}$.

You have also stated that $\angle CAE = 60^{\circ}$. **In this case, point $G$ must be equal to point $A$ (the center of the circle)**. That's the only possibility that could explain $\angle CGE = \angle CAE = 60^{\circ}$.

So the areas $CGF = CAF = EGD = EAD = 30 cm^2$. With that in mind, we can find the radius of the circle $R$:
$$
Area_{CAF} = Area_{EAD} = \cfrac{\theta  R^2}{2} = \cfrac{\pi R^2}{6} = 30 cm^2 \therefore R^2 = \cfrac{180}{\pi} \therefore R = \sqrt{\cfrac{180}{\pi}}
$$

Finally, the areas $CGE$ (= $CAE$) and $FGD$ (= $FAD$)  can be found:

$$
Area_{CGE} = Area_{FGD} = \cfrac{\theta R^2}{2} = \cfrac{\pi R^2}{12} = \cfrac{\pi}{12} \cfrac{180}{\pi} = 15 cm^2
$$